# MongoDB ObjectId foreign key implementation recommendation

Tags: mongodb, foreign-keys, pymongo, database, nosql

I'm looking for a recommendation on how best to implement MongoDB foreign key `ObjectId` fields. There seem to be two possible options, either containing the nested `_id` field or without.

Take a look at the **fkUid** field below.

```
{'_id':ObjectId('4ee12488f047051590000000'), 'fkUid':{'_id':ObjectId('4ee12488f047051590000001')} }
```

OR

```
{'_id':ObjectId('4ee12488f047051590000000'), 'fkUid':ObjectId('4ee12488f047051590000001')} }
```

Any recommendations would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

I'm having a hard time coming up with any possible advantages for putting an extra field "layer" in there, so I would personally just store the `ObjectId` directly in `fkUid`.

Comment: totally agree. Adding a subdocument makes it harder to query, harder to update, take up more space and probably slower. I'd also drop the 'fk' prefix. If your `Message` has a `SenderId` that is pretty obvious.

Comment: yep, agreed with dropping that prefix.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use default dbref implementation, that is described here http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+References and is compatible with most of specific language drivers.

Comment: I disagree. This quote from docs sums it up pretty nicely: "Unless you have a compelling reason for using DBrefs, use manual references". It depends on usage case of course, but this is not a good general-practice advice.

Comment: "many drivers automatically resolve DBRefs" - this is compelling enough for me. Also it is easier to support such references in a large database structure. I agree that for small tasks where you are completely sure what are you doing it is just fine to use direct reference.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about the naming of the field (what you have in the title), usually the convention is to name it after the object to which it refers.

Answer (score 0):

The both ways that you have mentioned are one of the same meaning. But they have different kind of usages.

Storing fkUid like `'fkUid':{'_id':ObjectId('4ee12488f047051590000001')}` an object has it's own pros. Let me give an example, Suppose there is a website where users can post images and view images posted by other users as well. But when showing the image the website also shows the name/username of the user. By using this way you also can store the details like `'fkUid':{'_id':ObjectId('4ee12488f047051590000001'), username: 'SOME_X'}`. When you are getting details from the db you don't have to send a request again to get the username for the specific `_id`.

Where as in the second way `'fkUid':ObjectId('4ee12488f047051590000001')} }` you have to send another request to the server only for getting the name/username and nothing else is useful from the same object.